# How do I disable ms query's auto wrapping of column aliases with quotes in excel 2007?

Tags: excel, ms-office, ms-query

I'm working on a sheet that accesses a legacy data source via MS Query. I'm trying to alias some of the ridiculously ugly column names but the data source doesn't support wrapping alias names with quotes. Since excel is automatically wrapping aliases in quotes the query errors/fails. I seem to be stuck.

How do I stop this default behavior?

I'd rather not use VBA for this case. I'm really just trying to figure out if I can get MS Query to alias these columns without wrapping them in single quotes.

I found some articles talking about registry entries/hot fixes. But they all refer to earlier versions of excel and the reg entries don't exist for 07.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around.

If I edit the SQL directly from the Connection Properties -> Definition tab (And not from within MS Query) the resulting query won't have auto wrapped aliases.

Small box to work with, but nothing copy paste won't solve :)